# ORA-01476: "divisor is equal to zero" for SQL query (Oracle 10g)

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm creating an SQL Query under oracle 10g, the result should give me something like that :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEXT         VALUE1        VALUE2          VALUE3               VALUE4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEXT1        8795           5684        value1-value2          value3/value2*100
TEXT2        235             568            ...                   ...
TEXT3        125             23             ...                   ...
TEXT4        789             58             ...                   ...
TEXTN         0               0             ...                   ...
```

when i try to calculate VALUE4 column i get this error :

```
ORA-01476: le diviseur est égal à zéro
01476. 00000 -  "divisor is equal to zero"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I tried `DECODE` function but i stil have the same error, it's the same for `CASE`

*NB : VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3 and VALUE4 are calculated columns; VALUE1 = sum(col1)+sum(col2).. and so for other VALUE2 column.*

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It all depends on whether you want to calculate a value if it would result in an infinite value or not. You can either ignore these particular instances and calculate on the remainder as [Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17022729/458741) suggests with:

```
case when value2 <> 0 then value3 / value2 * 100 end
```

Alternatively, if want to ignore them you can use [`NULLIF()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions116.htm#SQLRF00681) to change the value to NULL and not calculate anything:

```
value3 / nullif(value2, 0) * 100
```

I do not understand your contention that this being a calculated column causes an issue. If it's a virtual column then your table would never have created, as specified in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402) a virtual column cannot refer to another by name.

If it's not a virtual column then you can do this in a select statement as normal.

Comment: take a look on my post, i modified some information and i gave an original query

Comment: nullif resolved my problem, now i have all numm in the botton of the result of the query. thanks Ben@

Answer (score 5):

In your code, where you have:

```
select value3/value2*100 as value4
```

You should have:

```
select (case when value2 <> 0 then value3/value2*100 end) as value4
```

Given your question:

```
select value1, value2, value3,
       (case when value2 is not null then value3 / value2 * 100 end) as value4
from (select value1, value2, (value1 - value2) as value3
      from . . .
     )
```

Comment: value3 is a calculated column, this is the problem!! and it will not be clean because i have a long WHERE clause, that i should include for this select

Comment: @archavin . . . Use a subquery or CTE to define the variables, and then do the comparison using the variables.

Comment: if i use subquery it will be so long, i would like to use decode i think it will resolve my problem, but i dont know why i get the same error when i use it. i use decode(round(sum(col1)+col(2)+..sum(coln)), 0, null, anynumber);

Comment: You can take a look at my original query, maybe it will be more clear